# Stop all running animations when a new transition occurs?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have a set of elements where I want to highlight elements that are currently executed or have previously been executed. This is far easier to understand when seen in action, so here we go:

[image: Highlighted execution]]

This "fading" behavior is achieved with the following animation:

```
trigger('isExecuted', [
  state('false', style({ "background": "white" })),
  state('true', style({ "background": "lime" })),
  transition('false => true', animate(0)),
  transition('true => false', animate(1000))
]),
```

It immediately animates to the "full" lime colour when going from `false` to `true` and slowly fades out when going the other way.

Sadly this behaves incorrectly when the same execution block is being executed again while still fading out. If you watched the video above closely, you might have gotten a glimpse at a state where the little cog is turning on `goForward()` or `wait()` but the block was not coloured green. If I remove the `wait()` block in the code, the problem becomes much more obvious: Many iterations do show the cog (= are being executed) but are not colored.

[image: No waiting, loads of cogs without green]

I guess this is because Angular wants to properly finish the previous animation (which is still fading out). Is there a way to tell Angular to only use the most recent animation at any time?

Comment: You're problem is that the `white` to `lime` animation of 1000ms does not switch back to `white` immediately when the cog is removed? I'm having a hard time understanding.

Comment: I think you need to set the *start* style state of the `transition()` first, and then the *end* style state of the animation for each transition. As you have it right now, the animation is applied to the current style of the trigger. Which doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: My problem is the contrary: I want a fully "lime" background everytime the cog is visible and then gradually fade the color back to white. But if the cog "comes back" during the fade-out, the color should jump back to "lime" immediatly.

Comment: The cog is shown when `isExecuted` equals "true"?

Comment: Yes, I added this clarification to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by accident: It seems that stating `animate(0)` triggers the (for me unwanted) behavior of applying the animation only after the other animation has finished. During some refactoring I (by accident) simply did not state a transition for `false => true` (which I refactored to `neutral => executed`) at all and suddenly the application of the style became instant.

```
trigger('background', [
  state('neutral', style({ "background": "white" })),
  state('executed', style({ "background": "lime" })),
  transition('executed => neutral', animate('2000ms)'))
])
```

[image: Working execution tracing]